# Saving Model in python without using sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am building a DL model from scratch i.e using only core library like **numpy** and **matplotlib**. I **do not intend to use** any **sklearn packages** in my project.

Is there any way I can *save my trained model* using core python and the core libraries I mentioned above?

- If **yes** how can I *save* and *retrieve* the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numpy includes several methods to save arrays to file. I like [np.savez_compressed()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez_compressed.html) because it allows you to save multiple arrays in compressed format in a single file. Just save your trained weights and all hyperparameters in such a .npz file and rebuild your model from there. You can retrieve them with `np.load()`.